# Why does ArrowHelper not hit the target?

Tags: three.js

Why does the tip of the below `ArrowHelper` not directly hit the target sphere? It just misses it a bit. Is the below direction calculation not precise enough?

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 16);
var material =  new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.type = "node";
mesh.position.set(30, -87, -11);
scene.add(mesh);

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 16);
material =  new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.type = "node";
mesh.position.set(28, 44, -14);
scene.add(mesh);

var sourcePos = new THREE.Vector3(30, -87, -11);
var targetPos = new THREE.Vector3(28, 44, -14);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(targetPos, sourcePos);
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.clone().normalize(), sourcePos, direction.length(), 0xff0000);
scene.add(arrow);
```

This is a direct follow up question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801371/why-does-my-cylinder-not-hit-the-spheres) (I left it open as there are maybe better algorithms without `ArrowHelper`, but it seems the inaccuracy there is caused by the ArrowHelper problem described here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a precision problem in three.js r.58 when handling cases in which the arrow points approximately "straight up" -- or "straight down".

I think you will find that it works fine in other cases.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will there be a solution for upcoming releases? Is this already fixed in HEAD? I there an open issue to follow? How about older versions?

Comment: As a work-around, you can add more 9's to the 0.999 constant in `ArrowHelper.js`. We'll fix it in the next release.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your work-around worked :-) Thanks for all the hard work!